# Activerecord associations as JSON with Grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord, ruby-grape

Is there a simple way to return activerecord models with associations as JSON using the Grape microframework?

```
get 'users' do
  User.includes(:address)
end
```

This snippet isn't working and `User.includes(:address).to_json(include: :address)` will get encoded twice as JSON. (To use the `to_json` method on my own doesn't feel right anyway)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to use `#as_json` instead.

So you can do

```
User.includes(:address).as_json(include: :address)
```

and that gives you a hash instead of a json string.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a good application for the [grape-active_model_serializers](https://github.com/jrhe/grape-active_model_serializers) plugin.

It will manage serializing the objects into JSON for you, including embedding associations by default, and it's extremely configurable if you want/need to override its defaults.