# ActiveRecord::Base has_many fetch all for a given parent

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rack, ruby-grape

### Question

Below I give my current API result, however, given the SQL that is executed it isn't my Expected or Desired Result.  Can anyone assist me in getting the second SQL queries results instead of the first?

### Models

**console_game.rb**

```
class ConsoleGame < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'console_game'
    self.primary_key = :id

    has_many :configurations, :class_name => 'Configuration'
end
```

**configuration.rb**

```
class Configuration < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'configuration'
    self.primary_key = :id
end
```

### API

```
resource :configuration do
  desc "Finds all configurations associated with a game."
  params do
    requires :game, type: String, desc: "Game search.", documentation: { example: 'Battlefield 3' }
  end
  route_param :game do
    get do
      ConsoleGame.where(value: 'Battlefield 3').includes(:configurations)
    end
  end
end
```

### Debug Console

> D, [2014-05-06T15:11:59.071493 #31068] DEBUG -- :   ConsoleGame Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `console_game`.* FROM `console_game`  WHERE `console_game`.`value` = 'Battlefield 3'
>   D, [2014-05-06T15:11:59.073289 #31068] DEBUG -- :   Configuration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `configuration`.* FROM `configuration`  WHERE `configuration`.`console_game_id` IN (2)
>   127.0.0.1 - - [06/May/2014 15:12:08] "GET /configuration/game HTTP/1.1" 200 34 25.9740

### Result - get /configuration/game

```
[
    {
        id: 2,
        value: "Battlefield 3"
    }
]
```

### Desired Result - get /configuration/game

```
[
    {
        id: 2,
        value: "x",
        device: 4,
        system: null,
        console_game_id: 2,
        creator: "yrdy",
        created_date: null,
        positive_votes: 0,
        negative_votes: 0
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        value: "ffds",
        system: 2,
        console_game_id: 2,
        creator: "gdfs",
        created_date: null,
        positive_votes: 0,
        negative_votes: 0
    }
]
```

*Note: There are a lot of foreign indexes on this table and i'd like to resolve them all but perhaps thats for another day.*

Result of `ConsoleGame.where(value: 'Battlefield 3').includes(:configurations).as_json(include: :configurations)`

```
[
    {
        id: 2,
        value: "Battlefield 3",
        configurations: [
            {
                id: 2,
                value: "ffds",
                device: 4,
                system: null,
                console_game_id: 2,
                creator: "yrdy",
                created_date: null,
                positive_votes: 0,
                negative_votes: 0
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                value: "x",
                device: 4,
                system: 2,
                console_game_id: 2,
                creator: "gdfs",
                created_date: null,
                positive_votes: 0,
                negative_votes: 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: @UriAgassi I posted my current Results and my desired Results...I want to get my desired results but I don't understand given that it is executing all the correct SQL why it isn't returning the right results.  Updated to have question, hopefully to more clearly define what the goal is

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137521/activerecord-associations-as-json-with-grape

Comment: @UriAgassi I'm getting `JSON` back, the issue is that my `.includes` is ran as a second SQL query but my `JSON` result is the result of the first query not the second.

Comment: You are querying `ConsoleGame` and expecting to get configurations. You should set up a relationship in the other direction from `Configuration` to `ConsoleGame` and query `Configuration.joins(:console_game).where(console_game:{value:'Battlefield 3'})` this will return `Configuration`s instead of games. or look at scopes which seems even better for you.

Comment: Have you tried simply: `ConsoleGame.where(value: 'Battlefield 3').configurations` ?

Comment: @BroiSatse I hadn't I got the following result : `{ }`

Comment: @abc123 - Hm, that should work. What does `ConsoleGame.where(value: 'Battlefield 3').configurations` give you in the console?

Comment: @BroiSatse `ConsoleGame.where(value: 'Battlefield 3').configurations` gives only `127.0.0.1 - - [06/May/2014 15:47:18] "GET /configuration/game HTTP/1.1" 200 2 0.0043` in the console no SQL at all

Comment: @abc123 - Oh geez, you need to be extra careful, you have a name clash on your model. My advice is to change name of `configurations` name to sth else. It might not seem as the problem now, but It might give you a headache in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
class ConsoleGame < ActiveRecord::Base
  #self.table_name = 'console_game'
  #self.primary_key = :id

  has_many :configurations #, :class_name => 'Configuration'
end

class Configuration < ActiveRecord::Base
  #self.table_name = 'configuration'
  #self.primary_key = :id
  belongs_to :console_game #, class_name: "ConsoleGame", primary_key: 'console_game_id', foreign_key: 'id'  #added relationship for ConsoleGame
end

resource :configuration do
  desc "Finds all configurations associated with a game."
    params do
      requires :game, type: String, desc: "Game search.", documentation: { example: 'Battlefield 3' }
    end
    route_param :game do
      get do
        #Search Configurations based on console game
        Configuration.joins(:console_game).where(console_game:{value: 'Battlefield 3'})
      end
    end
end
```

Better yet add a scope

```
class Configuration < ActiveRecord::Base
  #self.table_name = 'configuration'
  #self.primary_key = :id
  belongs_to :console_game #, class_name: "ConsoleGame", primary_key: 'console_game_id', foreign_key: 'id'  #added relationship for ConsoleGame
  scope :by_game,->(game){
           #verbosely
           #game_ids = ConsoleGame.where(value: game).pluck(:id)
           #where(console_game_id: game_ids)
           #one line
           joins(:console_game).where(console_game:{value: game})
           }
end
```

Use as

```
Configuration.by_game('Battlefield 3')
```

**EDIT**

I have commented out the lines that are not needed because they are implied by design

Comment: I defined it as `belongs_to :console_game, :class_name => 'ConsoleGame'` but this does work.  Scope works as well thank you, this really helped me understand this better...I am just starting with ruby and am doing database first so these classes were generated.

Comment: @abc123 no problem. Also as a heads up `:id` is always assumed to be the `primary_key` so you don't have to say so I have commented out the lines that are not needed to show you